# Flutter firebase java.io.IOException: PHONE REGISTRATION ERROR

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

On some Android devices, when Firebase.instance.getToken appears, this exception appear. although api key support all firebase installation services.

```
Future<String> getDeviceToken() async {
  try {
    String? token;
    token = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken() ?? '';
    return Future.value(token);
  } catch (e) {
    return Future.value("");
  }
}
```